# How to set the default browser for a Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build an Angular 2 application using VSCode editor. On my machine the default browser is IE. When I run `npm start` it launches the application in IE. But I want to launch my application in Chrome.

How can I change this behaviour to launch Chrome instead of IE with `npm start`?

Comment: change your default browser to chrome at chrome setting.

Comment: ahh, no I do not want to do that. On machine I want to keep the default browser to IE but for debugging I want to use chrome. In Visual Studio 2013/2015 we have the option to launch the URL with the preferred browser. I am looking for the same in VS code. - Atul

Comment: Is not VS Code, is npm that start a new browser, and it start the default one

Comment: Eventually, open your package.json file and have a look inside your "script" section. you can edit/create your own npm command there

Comment: I am also looking for same. Looks like this option is still not there.see this two threads  1) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1245  2) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try it using `package.json`, as a workaround for default browser. Look into the `"scripts"` and find `"start"`. Use this code snippet:

`"start": "start {browser} http://{projectsite} && ng serve"`

With `{browser}` as your preferred browser (in this case, use `chrome`), and `{projectsite}` as the site where the application is started (if you haven't changed any of the setting for the test, still use `localhost:4200`).

If you want to test it, use `npm start` to run these commands. It should start the browser first before compiling the angular project so you would see a "page not found" before switching to your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VS_Code as your IDE then go to `.vs > vscode > launch.json` in that check for the below.

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:PortNo",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",

}
```

Comment: what is .vs? Where do we find it? I am using Mac so excuse me for such stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, go to the Run view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and click on the gear button to create a launch. json debugger configuration file. Choose Chrome from the Select Environment drop-down list. This will create a launch.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to Google chrome setting -> go to default browser(see on left side) ->
click on make default -> then search web browser click on web browser you see chrome just click (you see chrome is default browser now)-> then Run your command ng s -o

Comment: Either a screen shot, or a bulleted list, may help the readability/clarity of your answer.

Comment: This changes the default browser to Chrome. What OP wanted is to keep the default browser as IE while using Chrome for debugging as per the comment below the post.