# How do I use Safari as my browser for debugging when using Visual Studio Code running an Angular app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, safari, vscode-debugger

I have an Angular app (.Net Core backend). I can create configurations in the launch.json file and debug with Firefox, Chrome, Edge, etc. But I don't see any option for Safari!

**QUESTION** - How do I create a configuration for Safari to use instead of Chrome when launching the debugger? When I click 'add configuration' in launch.json, which option do I select for Safari? Do I need a separate extension?

Comment: I have this same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66649520/14933870)

Comment: no, unfortunately not.

Comment: have you tried setting the `runtimeExecutable` to Safari? I dont' own a Mac so I can't test, but it might have a similar enough debugging protocol to chrome. Otherwise, it's not natively supported by VS Code

Answer (score 0):

I found some links for you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738121
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942204

Set the `BROWSER` environment variable before executing the start command may help.

This environment variable is documented here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

> By default, Create React App will open the default system browser, favoring Chrome on macOS. Specify a browser to override this behavior, or set it to none to disable it completely. If you need to customize the way the browser is launched, you can specify a node script instead. Any arguments passed to npm start will also be passed to this script, and the url where your app is served will be the last argument. Your script's file name must have the .js extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).