# Set up default browser for npm serve of a react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

How can i change the default browser fired up when running `npm start` for a `create-react-app` created app?

It'll run *Firefox* but I'd like the *Chrome*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these links might help:

1. https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/open-create-react-app-in-a-specific-browser
2. [create-react-app: How do I "npm start" with a specific browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706882/create-react-app-how-do-i-npm-start-with-a-specific-browser)

Both set the `BROWSER` environment variable before executing the start command.
In your case you'll have to edit the `start` command `package.json` file according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59882442/10250548